# Mobile app development: Native vs hybrid vs PWA

Tags: mobile, native, progressive-web-apps, hybrid

Am new to mobile development but what I've gathered is there are below three approaches to implement it:

i) Native (IOS/Android)
ii) Hybrid
iii) PWA (Progressive WebApps)

**Question:**
Given a business use case that needs to delivered to its users via mobile, what questions do we need to ask of a use case to help understand if the use case is a better candidate for Native, Hybrid or PWA?

Thanks much for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required native capabilities...
Performance e.g. Usually PWAs work slower than a native app
Cost
Potential Web experience (if any)
..... and more